# sqlalchemy fails to connect but cx_oracle succeeds

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I'm attempting to connect to an oracle server in Python. I have this working in cx_Oracle, but when I try to connect using sqlalchemy it fails. The cx_Oracle code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

cx_connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user+'/' + pw + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + db)
df = pd.read_sql(my_query, cx_connection)
```

Executes and returns data from the database based on the query as expected. If I try the same connection with sqlalchemy:

```
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://' + user + ':' + pw + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + db)
sqlalchemy_connection = engine.connect()
```

I get an error on the last line:

> DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-12505: TNS:listener does
>   not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor (Background on
>   this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)

Any idea what the problem is? Isn't sqlalchemy just using cx_Oracle? Is there any workaround to just give the cx_Oracle connection to sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per the [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#dialect-oracle-cx_oracle-connect), the format of your Oracle connection string with SQLAlchemy should be `oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:port/dbname[?key=value&key=value...]`. But based on your former connection string, the db value might actually be the TNS service name, so in this case, you want to use

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://' + user + ':' + pw + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/?service_name=' + db)
```

Comment: Oops, in trying to simplify for this post I neglected to notice the connection strings aren't the same. I've edited the question to show the problem with the engine creation line you have.

Comment: @Kewl Ok, in this case, looking at your connection string pattern in the former example, it looks like it follows this pattern per this [site](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-fix-ora-12505-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descriptor/): `username/password@host:port/SERVICE_NAME`. Therefore, the possible method is following this pattern in sqlalchemy: `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://' + user + ':' + pw + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/?service_name=' + db)`. Let me know if it works and I will edit my answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Update the answer and I'll upvote and accept it

Comment: doesn't work for me `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (cx_Oracle.OperationalError) ORA-03135: connection lost contact` but the `cx_oracle.connect` works

Comment: I have the same experience as @TomSawyer and was not able to get it to work. I didn't need to use sqlalchemy so I just used the cx_oracle connection and got what I needed.