# Can't access Oracle database using sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oracle11g, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I'm aware that this one has been asked several times - particularly in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48951981/sqlalchemy-fails-to-connect-but-cx-oracle-succeeds), but I have not managed to solve my problem. Both snippets below have cx_Oracle and sqlalchemy installed

```
import cx_Oracle
from sqlachemy import create_engine
```

I'm trying to connect/write a pandas dataframe to an Oracle Database. I've managed to write to the database using the following code snippet:

```
ora_con = cx_Oracle.connect("{}/{}@{}".format(schema_name, password, name_of_service))
cur = ora_con.cursor()
statement='CREATE TABLE '+schema_Name+'.History (Name VARCHAR2(15), Entity VARCHAR2(15), Status VARCHAR2(25), Type VARCHAR2(25), Owner VARCHAR2(15), User_521 VARCHAR2(15), Manufacturer  VARCHAR2(15), Model  VARCHAR2(15), FusInv_Last_inventory DATE, Serial_Number  VARCHAR2(25), ID VARCHAR2(15), Version_of_OS  VARCHAR2(15), OS  VARCHAR2(15), Date_of_Report DATE)'
cur.execute(statement)
```

That works.

When I try:

```
con_str = """oracle+cx_oracle://schema_name:password@Host_address:port/?service_name=name_of_service"""
engine = create_engine(con_str, echo=False)
pandasDataframe.to_sql('History', engine ,  index = False) # Insert the values from the INSERT QUERY into the table 'History'
```

The pandas .to_sql command fails with a cx_Oracle error of:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure

Googling the error indicates a networking error (network is fine) or a listener error (Port number, but that is also fine)

I can connect, write and read the database in SQL Developer.

Any thoughts anyone? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plain cx_Oracle connect string is different from the one for sqlalchemy. Note that sqlalchemy uses `cx_Oracle.makedsn()`. So if you have this connect syntax with plain cx_Oracle:

```
cx_Oracle.connect('myuser/mypassword@myhost:myport/myservice')
```

you would need this syntax for sqlalchemy:

```
con_str = 'oracle+cx_oracle://myuser:mypassword@myhost:myport/?service_name=myservice'
```

Comment: Thanks - got it going now. Now the df.to_sql is failing with a different error :-( - but at least I am connecting to the database now

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it!